# Почему я прохожу капчу, вставляя ее код текстовое поле капчу в, а сайт ее не засчитывает?

Tags: captcha

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прохожу капчу используя rucaptcha, беру выданные код и вставляю в текстовое поле, сайт должен засчитать, что я прошел капчу и разблокировать кнопку "Далее" но почему то этого не происходит

Comment: почему сайт должен засчитать, что прошел?

Comment: потому что при прохождении капчи в это поле подставлется ключ решения. я прошел капчу через сторонний сервис и сма сюда вставил код, следовательно сымитировал работу

Comment: а почему ты думаешь, что ключ решения стороннего сервиса такой же, как на этом сайте?

Comment: rucaptcha использовал всегда. всегда работало, когда мог сделать на запросах